# cURL code for registration form to web app not working showing top of page

Tags: php, forms, post, curl, web

I have created a cURL php file & included it into my index.php file. Part of the code is displaying at the top of the page. I'm not the best PHP coder, but I believe it is correctly coded. Here is the code for the PHP file:

```
<?php

//array of data to be posted
$post_data = array(
   'FirstName' => urlencode($firstname),
   'LastName' => urlencode($lastname),
   'UserIdentifier' => urlencode($regemail),
   'Password' => urlencode($regpass),
   'ReferrerAttribution' => '[referrer here]'
);
//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//final string using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connect
$curl_connection =
  curl_init('https://integration.[domain here].com/v1/[folder here]');

//set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

//set header
$header = array (
        'POST https://integration.[domain here].com/v1/[folder here] HTTP/1.1\r\n',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n',
        'Authorization: Basic "[auth key here]"\r\n'
 );
//set post data
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//show request info
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
                curl_error($curl_connection);

//close
curl_close($curl_connection);

?>
```

Here is the error at the top of the page:

```
Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle resource in /home/[main]/public_html/[folder]/signup.php on line 24
    Array ( [url] => https://integration.[domain].com/v1/[folder] [content_type] => text/html [http_code] => 401 [header_size] => 381 [request_size] => 285 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 2.294219 [namelookup_time] => 0.002752 [connect_time] => 0.081426 [pretransfer_time] => 0.26445 [size_upload] => 74 [size_download] => 58 [speed_download] => 25 [speed_upload] => 32 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => 74 [starttransfer_time] => 0.345831 [redirect_time] => 0 ) 0-
```

The [] brackets are to show info I can't make public. Thanks for any help in advance. Oh, this is my 1st post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! In the following line of code you pass an invalid parameter $ch which has not been defined. Change it to $curl_connection.

**Was:**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

**Should be:**

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

**Edit:**

You also never applied the headers you defined to your request. You should do this:

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that! [hitting self in forehead!]... I have another problem: The $header array seems to be displaying at the top too? Not completely sure it is the $header but seems to be.

Comment: Not a problem. After all, it is Friday. Check my edit above for applying header information. Might solve your problem. If not- then I'm afraid I don't see a reason why that would happen.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful! Unfortunately I know get this error:

Comment: You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, CURLOPT_QUOTE, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES and CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE arguments

Comment: Make sure you are defining $header = array(..); BEFORE your call to the curl_setopt() function, otherwise it will be passing a undefined variable. Typically I define the headers array before I configure curl.. just to avoid that issue.

Comment: I inserted the setopt for the header after defining the header & I still get the array displaying at the top of the page?

Comment: print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection)); Seems like a culprit to me.

Comment: Doesn't that just show the curl output? This is where my lack of experience comes into play. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: $result will contain the output from the request. According to the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php: If opt is given, returns its value as a string. Otherwise, returns an associative array with the following elements (which correspond to opt), or FALSE on failure

Comment: Thanks, I will comment out: "print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
                curl_error($curl_connection);"